How can I read files into wstring?
I'm trying to open file using wifstream:
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

wstring readFile(const char* filename)
{
    wifstream wif(filename);
    wstringstream wss;
    wss << wif.rdbuf();
    return wss.str();
}

It is reading file that conatains english and russian symbols and placing text into wstring.
Then, I tried to print all of that into console and all russian symbols were replaced with another. English symbols were correct.
I found, that all characters codes (like \u...) of replaced symbols are right. Also them were out of ASCII table, like å - U+00E5 (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters)
I think there's problem in decoding file into utf-8.

So the file is encoded in UTF-8? There is absolutely no guarantee that your code will decode UTF-8. If you want that you will have to write the code yourself.

If it's UTF-8 enocoded, just read it into a std::string (or std::u8string). You also don't need a stringstream. Just create the string from iterators: return {std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(wif), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{}};

What you should do is use your debugger to examine the wstring in memory. Because the other thing that can go wrong is printing the string to the console. It could be that the string is correct when you read it, but the printing doesn't work. And both the reading and the printing could be wrong of course.

U+00E5 is Cyrillic 'e' in Windows-1251 character encoding. The file seems to be 8 bit Windows-1251 encoded, nor UTF-8 and nor UCS-2.

Obviously the first thing you need to establish is the encoding of your input file. You won't get anywhere without that. The text editor 'notepad++' has a handy feature where it tries to guess the encoding of a file. I've found it to be extremely reliable, maybe you should download it.

This question is similar to: Read Unicode UTF-8 file into wstring. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I checked encoding. It really was Windows-1251. I changed it into UTF-8. Symbols also changed, their codes are correct, but they are not as in file still. (console prints all symbols correct, I checked in debugger)

@TedLyngmo, sorry, your code didn't really helped, symbols changed, but there wasn't symbols from file. File is utf-8 encoded

@illi4er My code by-passes the stringstream but doesn't fix your problem. If the file is really UTF-8 encoded, then using a std::string or std::u8string will work: std::string readFile(const char* filename) { std::ifstream wif(filename); return {std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(wif), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{}}; }

@TedLyngmo Yes, I got that I should use std::string instead of std::wstring, but it didn't fixed replacement, symbols in std::string are also different from symbols in file

The string should contain the exact same thing as your file.

@AndrewYim The linked question is specifically about Windows. While the accepted answer is platform-independent, it uses the std::codecvt_utf8 facet, which is currently deprecated and is due to be removed by C++26.

Without any additional set-up, wifstream will use the C locale, which is probably not what you want.
There are multiple possible solutions:

1. Using the default locale
To read files using the default locale, use std::wifstream with std::locale(""). This is how most Linux programs work.
Example:
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

int main()
{
    std::wifstream stream("sample.txt");
    if (!stream)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file\n";
        return 1;
    }

    stream.imbue(std::locale(""));

    for (auto c : std::views::istream<wchar_t>(stream))
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(c) << std::endl;
    }

    if (stream.bad())
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to extract character\n";
    }
}

Most Linux distros default to UTF-8. Windows can be configured to use UTF-8 too, although I believe that's not the default.

2. Using an UTF-8 locale
While there isn't really a fully portable way to do this, the following seems to work both on Windows and Linux (as long as the en_US.utf-8 locale is available):
stream.imbue(std::locale("en_US.utf-8"));


3. Using the deprecated (C++17) / removed (C++26) codecvt_utf8_utf16
WARNING: Do NOT use on production. Stuff from <codecvt> have issues related to error handling and are set to be removed from the standard. I also wouldn't trust them to properly handle malformed (or potentially malicious) input.
stream.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), new std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>));


4. Using a library
This is realistically the best option for production code that can't simply rely on the default locale.

So which approach should you choose? It depends:

If you just want to do some quick testing, option #2 is probably the simplest. Just don't use it on production;
If it's acceptable (or even desirable, if you're targeting Linux) for your program to use the default locale, use option #1;
Otherwise, use #4.

